# How To Play Sound In WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I developing the game "minesweeper" ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_(video_game))), and I want to play sound when the user hit a bomb. How can I play a sound while the application is running?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WPF's MediaElement for this.
For more information, visit the official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.100).aspx